# Multi user database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I developp an application with potential multi users. My data is stored in a database with the content provider. I searched the best way to create the database. Actually, I have 3 ideas :

1. Single database - Add UserId column in each table
2. Single database - Remove all data at disconnection, so the next user will have a new empty database
3. Multi database - One database for each user (for exemple with the name {userId}-mydatabase.db)

Can someone know the best way to do this?
For information, data is not shared between users.

Comment: I'd choose **1** (or 3). Surely, **not 2**, since the data will be lost between sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to create a single database
and set the UserId column in each table (**Idea 1**)

If you have a really huge amount of datas maybe you should think to use the **Idea 3**.

But if you have for example a "*Super administrator*" account in your app who could see all the users you should choose the **first idea**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I finnaly choose the first idea.